# C#: Return reference to custom node in SortedSet

Tags: c#, reference, return, sortedset

Admittedly, it's been a long time since I've taken my data structures class, and I feel like I'm not fully understanding the concept of using trees. I need a structure that can hold a lot of 'nodes' and help me alter them. My first thought was a BST, but everyone has told me that C# has the even better SortedSet. However, I cannot find a way to alter a node, or report its position. Perhaps I'm using the wrong structure? Here's my 'nodes':

```
public class Node
{
    public string name { get; }
    public List<int> someList { get; set; }

    public Node(string s, int i)
    {
        name = s;
        someList = new List<int>();
        someList.add(i);
    }

    public void add(int i)
    {
        someList.Add(i);
    }

    public void remove(int i)
    {
        someList.Remove(i);
    }
}
```

Since I'll have roughtly 100,000 of these nodes, I would like them to be auto-sorted, as well as easily found and altered. Something like this:

```
SortedSet<Node> nodes = new SortedSet<Node>();
List<int> myList = {1, 2, 3};
Node node1 = new Node("myNode", myList)
nodes.Add(node1);
nodes.get("myNode").remove(2); //remove #2 from someList in node object
```

Perhaps a tree isn't the answer. I thought a BST would make binary searches much easier, but perhaps I'll just do List instead. Any advice is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: how does a `get` allow you to `remove`?

Comment: A `SortedSet<T>` where `T` is not `IComparable` and an `IComparer<T>` is not specified is going to throw once you add the second element. `SortedSet<T>` automatically maintains its order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary I think.

```
public class Node
{
    public string name { get; }
    public List<int> someList { get; set; }

    public Node(string s, List<int> i)
    {
        name = s;
        someList = i;
    }

    public void add(int i)
    {
        someList.Add(i);
    }

    public void remove(int i)
    {
        someList.Remove(i);
    }
}
```

Client

```
Dictionary<string, Node> nodes = new Dictionary<string, Node>();
List<int> myList = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3 };
Node node1 = new Node("myNode", myList);
nodes.Add(node1.name, node1);
nodes["myNode"].remove(2);
```

Assumption is that node names are unique.